# How to write correctly in file in C?

Tags: c

I have this function:

```c
void write_in_the_log_file(FILE *log_file, int tm_year, int tm_mon, int tm_mday,
                           int tm_hour, int tm_min, int tm_sec)
{
    log_file = fopen(ODIT, "a");
    fprintf(log_file, "Inventory at %02d.%02d.%02d - %02d:%02d:%02d\n", tm_mday, tm_mon, tm_year, tm_hour, tm_min,tm_sec);
    f_print_inventory(log_file);
    fprintf(log_file, "--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    fclose(log_file);
}
```

And I call it like this:

```c
  write_in_the_log_file(log_file, 
                        tm.tm_year + 1900, 
                        tm.tm_mon + 1, 
                        tm.tm_mday, 
                        tm.tm_hour, 
                        tm.tm_min, 
                        tm.tm_sec);
```

Where `tm` things are the time and they are declared like this:

```c
    time_t T = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&T);
```

Also `ODIT` is:

```c
#define ODIT "odit/log_file.txt"
```

The problem here is that it is saving it correctly but after it the program crashes with error:

```c
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: It is suspicious that you are passing a `FILE * log_file` as an argument, but you are also opening and closing the file within the function. I am going to assume that you attempt to close the file again in another piece of code you are not showing.

Comment: You should use `strftime` to format the time. It also seems to make more sense to just pass a pointer to a `struct tm` rather than passing 6 integers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac or Linux, then this path location system can be used, but if you are using Windows OS, then Kindly change the path as per windows path system

try this

```html
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void printData(void);
void ReadData(void);
void printData1(void);
void ReadData1(void);
void MergingFile(void);
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printData();
    printData1();
    ReadData();
    ReadData1();
    MergingFile();
    return 0;
}
void printData()
{
    char String[1000]; FILE *file = NULL;
    printf("%s\n\n","Write Few Lines of '30 words' in files to test in File 1 ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",String);
    file = fopen("/Users/hemant/firstFile.txt","w");
    fprintf(file, "%s",String);
    fclose(file);
}
void printData1()
{
    char Stringn[1000];
    FILE *file2 = NULL;
    printf("%s\n\n","Write Few Lines of '30 words' in files to test 2 ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",Stringn);
    file2 = fopen("/Users/hemant/secondFile.txt","w");
    fprintf(file2, "%s",Stringn);
    fclose(file2);
}
void ReadData()
{
       char str[1000];
        FILE *file3 = NULL;
        printf("%s\n\n","You are Reading from First File ");
        file3 = fopen("/Users/hemant/firstFile.txt","r");
        fscanf(file3,"%[^\n]",str);
        printf("%s\n",str);
        fclose(file3);
}
void ReadData1()
{
       char str[1000];
        FILE *file4 = NULL;
        printf("%s\n\n","You are Reading from Second File ");
        file4 = fopen("/Users/hemant/secondFile.txt","r");
        fscanf(file4,"%[^\n]",str);
        printf("%s\n",str);
        fclose(file4);
}
void MergingFile()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char str[2000],String1[1000],String2[1000];
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    FILE *first = NULL;
    FILE *second = NULL;
    printf("%s\n\n","You are Merging Both firstFile and Second Data into ThirdFile ");
    fp = fopen("/Users/hemant/ThirdFile.txt", "w");
    first = fopen("/Users/hemant/firstFile.txt", "r");
    second = fopen("/Users/hemant/secondFile.txt", "r");
    fscanf(first,"%[^\n]",String1);
    fscanf(second, "%[^\n]",String2);
    while (String1[i] != '\0') {
           str[j] = String1[i];
           i++;
           j++;
       }
       i = 0;
       while (String2[i] != '\0') {
           str[j] = String2[i];
           i++;
           j++;
       }
       str  [j] = '\0';
    
    fprintf(fp,"%s",str);
    
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(first);
    fclose(second);
}
```

Comment: I have just created program, with 3 options, read write and merge, now see, and edit according to your needs, and also, I have just used for short paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 problems in your function:

- what is the point of taking `log_file` as an argument in function `write_in_the_log_file`? If this argument is a valid stream pointer to the log file, use it directly instead of reopening the log file. Otherwise remove this argument and define `log_file` as a local variable.
- you do not test if `fopen()` succeeded at opening the log file. `ODIT` is a relative path `"odit/log_file.txt"` so `fopen()` may fail to open the log file if the current directory is not what you assume. You should test the return value and avoid undefined behavior if `log_file` is a null pointer.

Without a compilable program that exhibits the offending behavior, it is impossible to ascertain where the `double free` error originates. It looks like a side effect of code with undefined behavior such as the `write_in_the_log_file` if `log_file` is null, but this undefined behavior could also be anywhere in the rest of the program.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void write_in_the_log_file(int tm_year, int tm_mon, int tm_mday,
                           int tm_hour, int tm_min, int tm_sec)
{
    FILE *log_file = fopen(ODIT, "a");
    if (log_file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "error opening log file %s: %s\n",
                ODIT, strerror(errno));
    } else {
        fprintf(log_file, "Inventory at %02d.%02d.%02d - %02d:%02d:%02d\n",
                tm_mday, tm_mon, tm_year, tm_hour, tm_min, tm_sec);
        f_print_inventory(log_file);
        fprintf(log_file, "--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
        fclose(log_file);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the error and as i mentioned in my question it is opening the file and writing to it correctly.

Comment: @ДимитърМилчев: The problem is probably somewhere else in your code.

Comment: log file wasn't big enough an the memory was overwritten - that was the problem, but thanks